# VOIP Fax + Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, voip, asterisk, google-voice

I just moved into a new office and don't want to get a landline phone.  I'd kind of like to set up an Asterisk box and use Google Voice as my service provider.

The main things I'd like to have are:

1. Forward calls to my cellphone when I'm out of the office.
2. Handle sending and receiving faxes.

Is doing this with Asterisk + Google Voice possible and/or the way to go?  Or is there a better way to handle my situation?  I've got some Raspberry Pis lying around that I'd love to give a use to.

Thanks!

Comment: Not an expert on Google or the Pi, but I do know a bit about VOIP (hence comment, not answer)  VOIP and fax do not play well together, although sometimes it may work depending on the codec and protocol (there is a VOIp protocol for fax called T38).   You are better off finding a gateway to convert email to fax and vv - its easier and more reliable.  Forwarding calls to cellphone etc can work well with VOIP.  You might also prefer a provider who offers SIP or IAX rather then Google voice, although Asterisk can be made to work with it.  Also look at encryption while you are doing things.

Answer (score 1):

I did setup [RasPBX](http://www.raspberry-asterisk.org/documentation/) on my Raspberry Pi and I really like it. I didn't try to setup fax on it, but I saw option in documentation. Forwarding should work fine too, I forward all phone calls from G voice to my Russian cell phone thru another (Multifon-Megafone) sip provider.